# 'Documents' folder recovery

Tags: data-recovery

I use ubuntu 16.04 LTS.I had installed 'Ratsnake', an image annotation software and selected ~/Documents as the directory to save the Graphic and text annotations. After saving, the contents of the Documents folder have disappeared and only annotations are saved. Is there a way to recover the lost contents of Documents folder? I have tried 'Photorec', it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I know nothing about Ratsnake, but I wonder ... has it deleted your Documents contents or just mounted to it ? Type 'mount', is anything mounted to Documents ?

Comment: I checked it. There is nothing mounted to Documents. Yes, it has deleted Documents contents.

Comment: Moreover, I tried saving to different folders and it deletes the folder contents every time. Is there a way to recover the lost files?

Comment: Without trying to sound condescending, think you need to throw this Ratsnake in the bin. Do you have a backup system in place ? The only way I have recovered deleted files is with photorec, but you already tried that. I think this snake might have done a real good job in your Documents folder. Have you tried using photorec when booted from a live distro ?